# How to use mutate result as input to calc another column in R dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to calculate data for two new columns in a data.frame where the results are based on the value of the previous row. However, the previous row also needs to be calculated, which means that there is a dependency between the two columns (the input for one calculation is based on the output of another calculation). I could do it through a `for`, but maybe it's not the right way.

This is a sample for this case:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(0.91,0.98,1,1.1), B=c(0.81, 1.11, 0.83, 0.92), C=c(0.09,0.06,0.09,0.08))
df$D <- NA
df$E <- NA
df[1,]$D <- 0.0
```

I've been trying it through dplyr::mutate.

```
df %>%
    mutate(D = ifelse( lag(A) < 1, lag(E), lag(E) - lag(E) * lag(A)),
           E = B - (B - D) * exp(-C)
           )
```

This is how the output should be:

```
> df
     A    B    C          D          E
1 0.91 0.81 0.09 0.00000000 0.06971574
2 0.98 1.11 0.06 0.06971574 0.13029718
3 1.00 0.83 0.09 0.13029718 0.19051977
4 1.10 0.92 0.08 0.00000000 0.07073296
```

Comment: I don't understand how you perform the calculation. Can you explain the calculation behind values in expected output?

Comment: Basically, the value of column C depends on the values of column A of the previous row. If the previous row A is lower than 4, then C is equal to the value of the column D on the row before. Otherwise, C is the result of previous row `A * B`. The column D does not use the row before, but needs the result of column C to get the result of the formula: `B - (B - D) * exp(-C)`. Therefore, the first entry of the column D is initialized with zero.